# What's the algorithm to shift a bitmap so that it looks correct only from a specific angle to the screen?

Tags: algorithm, bitmap

I saw this:

[image]

Which is a $2.5 million dollar (physically) 3D display meant to show an image that looks right to viewers at the entrance of the building. [Link to animated version.](https://g.redditmedia.com/24MrlLGiMxtVVMboNTAhygW7mPjB0Elu7UC785Ups9M.gif?w=728&fm=mp4&mp4-fragmented=false&s=028792418aa9224523872184b60fe66f)

I was immediately interested in the code involved in rendering the original video bitmap in such a way as to stretch it so that it looks perfect from the correct angle in relation to the screen its being played on. But I realized it would be silly for me to spend time developing this when it's probably a well know algorithm that I can just look up, but I don't know what to search for.

Can someone tell me the algorithm or even just the name of the effect so I can find it?

Comment: Thanks for the instant down-vote with no comment stating the reason. 

I dont see why asking for the name of a specific rendering algorithm would be off-topic. It's going to be a specific algorithm designed for bitmaps, so probably off-topic for math.se and I really don't see why it wouldn't be a reasonable question here. I've worked a lot with bitmap algorithms and I'm fairly confident an algorithm should exist for doing this, published somewhere, but I just have no idea what it's called or what to search for.

Comment: I don't know who down voted... nor what the algorithm is... but the installation seems like it would have to do with perspective. There are art installations, which use this trick to assemble what seems like random objects (chairs, books, etc...) into a person's portrait & face, when viewed from the right perspective. Perhaps you could search online for "perspective algorithms"?

Comment: @Clomp thanks for the tip, Ill give it a shot.

Comment: I believe it's called Anamorphic Projection.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thanks, that's the answer.